# Change legend style from bar to line chart.js 2.4.0

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, chart.js

[image]I am using chart.js(2.4.0) for graph and i need to change the legend style from bar to line I am unable to do that.

How can i change legend from bar to line.

Following is my code

```
renderChart(id, labels, label1, label2, data1, data2, borderDash = [], pointRadius = 3, backgroundColor = '#36a1eb') {
data2 = data2 || [];
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{

        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        borderColor: '#36a1eb',
        lineColor: '#36a1eb',
        strokeColor: '#36a1eb',
        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
        borderDash: borderDash,
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
        pointBorderColor: '#36a1eb',
        pointBackgroundColor: '#36a1eb',
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#36a1eb',
        pointHoverBorderColor: '#36a1eb',
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: pointRadius,
        pointHitRadius: 10,
        label: label2,
        data: data2,
        borderWidth: 2

    }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false,
          beginAtZero: false
        },
          scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: 'Value'
          }
      }],

        xAxes: [{

          ticks: {
            reverse: false,
            beginAtZero: false
          },
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Date'
            }
        }],
    }
  }
};
```

How can i do this?
I searched all of the documentation of the chart.js but still unable to modify it to line.

Comment: Can you show screen of your result and exemple of what you search?

Comment: @CyrielleDev I need to change those lenged bars as lines,
see the update question, i have attached image

Comment: you put line type and they are bars anyway?

Comment: Your image have the line chart only.

Comment: @CyrielleDev i need the legend also has line

Answer (score 0):

The configuration options are available at
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration

Have you tried `boxWidth` or `usePointStyle`?

Comment: we have option to change the width of legend only but not the height... :( @Ben